# How to use python assignment operator with multiple return values

Tags: python-3.x, list, reduce, assignment-operator, compound-assignment

I have a Python function which takes a parameter and returns 2 outputs. I want to call this for all the elements in a list and combine the return values for each invocation as below:

```
a1, b1 = func(p[0])
a2, b2 = func(p[1])
a3, b3 = func(p[3])

a = a1 & a2 & a3
b = b1 + b2 + b3
```

How can I refactor this to a one liner using the `+=` , `&=` and the `reduce` operators in Python?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you specifically ask for the ``+=`` , ``&=`` and the ``reduce`` operators? By design, you cannot use ``+=`` and ``&=`` in the same statement (i.e. for practical purposes the same line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can decompose this problem into individual tasks:

- Mapping a function `func` across the elements `p[0]`, `p[1]`, ... of an iterable/sequence `p` is `map(func, p)`.

  - This already provides an iterable of `(a1, b1)`, `(a2, b2)` so the assignment does not need special handling.
- The chain of operations `a1 & a2 & ...` for a sequence/iterable `a` is `reduce(lambda new, total: new & total)` and likewise for `+`.

  - Since we have a stream of pairs of `(a1, b1), ...` instead of a pair of streams `a1, ...` and `b1, ...` we must operate on both at once.
- The result of reducing a stream of pairs is a single pair, which we can assign to two variables as `a, b = result`.

```py
from functools import reduce

def func(a): return a, a
p = range(1, 5, 2)


def reduction(new, total):
    return new[0] & total[0], new[1] + total[1]

mapped = map(func, p)
reduced = reduce(reduction, mapped)
a, b = reduced
```

If desired, this can be written in one statement/line.

```py
>>> a, b = reduce(lambda new, total: (new[0] & total[0], new[1] + total[1]), map(func, p))
>>> a
1
>>> b
4
```

Comment: Shouldn't your reduction function be ```return new[0] & total[0], new[1] + total[1]``` ?

Answer (score 2):

Since you want a one-liner, something like this should help you:

```
a,b = int(all(ele == list(zip(*map(func,p)))[0][0] for ele in list(zip(*map(func,p)))[0])),sum(list(zip(*map(func,p)))[-1])
```

**Breakdown:**

The `map` function applies a function to an iterable.

```
list(map(func,p))
```

Prints:

```
[(1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5)]
```

This:

```
list(zip([(1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5)]))
```

Prints:

```
[((1, 3),), ((2, 4),), ((3, 5),)]
```

Adding an `*` before `map` would transpose the `list`:

```
list(zip(*map(func,p)))
```

Prints:

```
[(1, 2, 3), (3, 4, 5)]
```

The `all` function is combined with a simple list comprehension in order to find if all elements of sublist 1 are equal. Here is a simpler version of it:

```
all(ele == lst[0] for ele in lst)
```

The same has been applied in this case like this:

```
all(ele == list(zip(*map(func,p)))[0][0] for ele in list(zip(*map(func,p)))[0])
```

Prints:

```
False
```

In order to convert `True`/`False` to `1`/`0`, I have used the `int()` function:

```
int(all(ele == list(zip(*map(func,p)))[0][0] for ele in list(zip(*map(func,p)))[0]))
```

Prints:

```
0
```

The second part of it, which is this: `sum(list(zip(*map(func,p)))[-1])` calculates the sum of the second sublist.

```
sum(list(zip(*map(func,p)))[-1])
```

Prints:

```
12
```

Here is the full code:

```
def func(a):
    return a,a+2

p = [1,2,3]

a,b = all(ele == list(zip(*map(func,p)))[0][0] for ele in list(zip(*map(func,p)))[0])),sum(list(zip(*map(func,p)))[-1])

print(a,b)
```

Output:

```
(0, 12)
```

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for adding the missing code (I assume you will fix it to be completely runnable and correct). Though to be honest, I have no idea how it actually works – in specific, translating the ``&`` operation to ``all``, ``==`` and several ``list(zip(...)[0]...`` parts is not obvious to me. Perhaps you can edit the answer to explain how your approach works?

Comment: Sure...I will do that.

Comment: Check out my latest edit and let me know whether the explanation is sufficient. Will I get an upvote from u?